# Add span after select a text

Tags: jquery

currently, I use a function to add a span to a text, if the user click a label at first and then select a part of the text.

**UPDATE** [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yL6g6wvb/2/)

**JS**

```
$(document).on('click', '#annotationModeArea label',
  function(){
    el = "";
    el = $(this);
    annotationMode(el);
});

function annotationMode(el) {
    var classes = $(el).attr('class').split(' ');
    var arr = classes,
    matches = new Array();
    matches = $.grep(arr, function(n, i) {
        return (n.search(/^c/i) > -1) ? true : false;
    });

     var activeClass = matches.join(", ");      


$('#resultText').unbind('mouseup').mouseup(function(event){

        var activeFastModeId = $(el).attr('id');

        var selection = getSelectedText();
        var selection_text = selection.toString();  


        var span = document.createElement('SPAN');
        span.className = "sentence s33 " + activeClass + " highlighted";   
        span.textContent = selection_text;
        var txt = selection_text;
        var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
        range.deleteContents();
        range.insertNode(span);


        event.stopPropagation();
       return false;
    });
}
```

Now I'm looking for the reversed way:

The user first selects the text and then click on the label. Only then the span should be created.

I am very grateful for tips. Thank you.

Comment: can you post html content too

Comment: jsfiddle would be nice

Comment: I ´ve added a jsFiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have update my code as per requirement you can check fiddle : **http://jsfiddle.net/yL6g6wvb/5/**

**HTML Code**

```
<p id="resultText">Except for some helicopters, the right seat in the cockpit of an aircraft is the seat used by the co-pilot. The captain or pilot in command sits in the left seat, so that he can operate the throttles and other pedestal instruments with his right hand. The tradition has been maintained to this day, with the co-pilot on the right hand side.</p>

<h2>labels</h2>

<div id="annotationModeArea">
    <button class="anLabel c1" id="aConcept">Concept</button>
    <button class="anLabel c3" id="aSentence">Sentence</button>
    <button class="anLabel c2" id="aAbbreviation">Abbreviation</button>
    <button class="anLabel c4" id="aAbstract">Abstract</button>
    <button class="anLabel c5" id="aCategory">Category</button>
    <button class="anLabel c6" id="aChunk">Chunk</button>
    <button class="anLabel c7" id="aChunkNP">ChunkNP</button>
    <button class="anLabel c8" id="aChunkPP">ChunkPP</button>
    <button class="anLabel c9" id="aChunkVP">ChunkVP</button>
    <button class="anLabel c10" id="aEntity">Entity</button>
</div>
```

**Jquery code**

```
function selectHTML() {
    try {
        if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            var c = document.selection.createRange();
            return c.htmlText;
        }

        var nNd = document.createElement("span");
        var w = getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        w.surroundContents(nNd);
        return nNd.innerHTML;
    } catch (e) {
        if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            return document.selection.createRange();
        } else {
            return getSelection();
        }
    }
}



$(function() {
    $('#annotationModeArea button').click( function() {
        var txt = $(this).text().toLowerCase();    
    var txtTrim = $.trim(txt);
    var classes = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
    var arr = classes,
    matches = new Array();
    matches = $.grep(arr, function(n, i) {
        return (n.search(/^c/i) > -1) ? true : false;
    });

     var activeClass = matches.join(", ");
        var mytext = selectHTML();
        $('span').addClass("sentence s33 " + activeClass + " highlighted");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but It do not work, I´ve added a jsFiddle with origin approach: click the label and then select the text.

Comment: There is still an issue in your jsFiddle, somethimes all spans will colored with the same colour / annotation